# JQuery not working after ajax update in jsf

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem. I use jquery in my jsf and primefaces application for simplify some operations. Jquery works fine onload page but when I update some component jquery not working. For example:

```
<h:form>

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{contractBean.workType}" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="product" itemValue="1"   />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="service" itemValue="2"   />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="product and service" itemValue="3" />
<p:ajax update="outPan" event="change" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputPanel id="outPan">
<p:inpuText value="#{contractBean.workType}" id="wType"/>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" id="sButton"/>
</p:outputPanel>

</h:form>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#sButton').prop('disabled',true);
$('#wType').css({'border':'red'})

})
</script>
```

Please help with your solutions. Thank you.

Comment: what you mean by "jquery not working" ?

Comment: Try changing `$(selector)`'s to `jQuery(selector)`. May be there is a conflict.

Comment: Maybe I did not correctly explained my problem. When page is open,  jquery works everywhere on page. But when I update outputPanel with ajax,  jquery do not  work in outpuPanel. Jquery continue works in another parts of page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Place your *js* code into a `function` and call it in `oncomplete` of your `p:ajax`

Like this

```
<p:ajax update="outPan" event="change" oncomplete="myFunc()" />
```

js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    myFunc();
});
function myFunc() {
    $('#sButton').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#wType').css({'border':'red'})
}
</script>
```

---

Explanation:

There is not ready event after primefaces ajax (after all it an ajax and not a full page reload)

If you want to hook some js code after the `p:ajax` , you can use its `onsuccess` attribute

Comment: Maybe I did not correctly explained my problem. When page is open,  jquery works everywhere on page. But when I update outputPanel with ajax,  jquery do not  work in outpuPanel. Jquery continue works in another parts of page.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer. It is working oncomplete event in my application.

Comment: You are welcome, you mean that your `onsuccess` does not fire? (place and `alert('hello')` to see if the `onsuccess` works... because if its not , it might means that there is some error somewhere... take a look at the browser console or networking response from server... (in chrome dev tools / bugzilla)

Comment: Onsuccess is indeed wrong hook if you intend to apply jQuery on the HTML elements which are only available after actual ajax update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028868/primefaces-pdialog-doesnt-always-show-up-if-update-dlg-in-commandbutton/15029403#15029403

Comment: @BalusC, but in plain `f:ajax` the `success` comes after `complete` and the jquery changes applied just fine..., primefaces changed the order of the terms/events in contradiction to the `f:ajax`?

Comment: That's in turn true. I must however admit that the PrimeFaces naming makes more sense. "success" must be interpreted as in, "ajax response is retrieved successfully". The failure condition is "error", which is then to be handled as `onerror`. If we follow standard JSF naming, you'd have `onerror` as counterpart of `oncomplete`. This makes no sense.

Comment: @BalusC , Thanks for the info , Since I'm a light primefaces user I wasn't aware of that... will fix my answer, And indeed you are right primefaces naming makes more sense , its just confuses that it does not match the jsf naming... Thanks again!

Comment: I have the same problem I have an script that execute selectors with Jquery and add some funcionality to p:datatable and it works ok until when I open and close a p:dialog wich update some parte of my principal page, my script simply not work. It seems that it goes away. So calling like a function: <p:ajax  event="close" oncomplete="myFunc()" />  (p:dialog event), it seems works but I have to put this snippet in all my app(p:dialogs), so my script might works. That is the solution?

Comment: @FernandoPie , I suggest you to try the Primefaces - AjaxFramework - Status - https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml , something like this should be used, `<p:ajaxStatus onsuccess="myFunc" />`

Answer (score 1):

fix the script you're using, selecting elements by id should be like that: $('#' + elemId)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#sButton').prop('disabled',true);
$('#wType').css({'border':'red'})

})
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I make an error when I wrote an example. I mean than when page loaded jquery work fine. But when update outputPanel jquery not working.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly do not think that the ID for button will be *sButton* when the page is rendered.
Usually in Jsf the Id of a component will be **formID:componentId**.
Co In your case since there is no ID for form, JSF will generate dynamic component ID like *jdt_k159* so you button id will be *jdt_k159:sButton*.
And also use **$('id=["xxx:yyy"]')** for safty in JQuery.

Give ID to the FORM as follows:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  ...
  ...
  <p:commandButton value="Submit" id="sButton"/>
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('[id="myForm:sButton"]').prop('disabled',true);
    ...
    ...
  })
</script>
```

Ref Links:
[Find component by ID in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378437/find-component-by-id-in-jsf)
[How to refer to a JSF component Id in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132061/how-to-refer-to-a-jsf-component-id-in-jquery)